# Code Double Equation Error for User Input Problem

Tags: java, math, input, equation

My first assignment is to develop a code that allows the user to input data for the distance in miles they wish to travel, the fuel efficiency, and the cost of gas. Then create a code in order to calculate the total cost of the trip.

I have all the code for all the input values but I'm having trouble with the equation itself. Java is not recognizing "/". I can't understand what I'm doing unless I need to add a bit more code for the equation to work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DrivingCost
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your distance (miles): ");

      Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please enter vehicle's fuel efficiency (mpg): ");

      Scanner u = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please enter the price per gallon (dollars): ");

      String distanceInMiles = s.nextLine();
      System.out.println("The distance (miles): " + distanceInMiles);

      String fuelEfficiency = t.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Fuel efficiency (mpg):" + fuelEfficiency);

        String pricePerGallon = u.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Price per gallon (dollars): " + pricePerGallon);

      double tripCost = (distanceInMiles / fuelEfficiency) * pricePerGallon;
      System.out.println("The trip cost (dollars): " + tripCost);
    }
}
```

This is the error I keep recieving:

```
DrivingCost.java:32: error: bad operand types for binary operator '/'
  double tripCost = (distanceInMiles / fuelEfficiency) * pricePerGallon;
                                     ^
```

Comment: You really should learn the difference between different data types such as [primitive types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) which includes `double` and [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). You might also find [Double.parseDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) useful.

Comment: Use only **one** scanner, no need to open multiple for a unique source

Comment: Math operation on words (String) think about it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're doing Math operation on String, you can't, you need `double` type

   - `Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());` reads a line and parse to a `double` (benefits : avoid return line error in general, good habit to have)
   - `sc.nextDouble()` reads directly for a `double`
2. Use only one Scanner per source
3. Have a good order between `print` and scanner asking

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter your distance (miles): ");
String distanceInMiles = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
System.out.println("The distance (miles): " + distanceInMiles);

System.out.print("Please enter vehicle's fuel efficiency (mpg): ");
String fuelEfficiency = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
System.out.println("Fuel efficiency (mpg):" + fuelEfficiency);

System.out.print("Please enter the price per gallon (dollars): ");
String pricePerGallon = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
System.out.println("Price per gallon (dollars): " + pricePerGallon);

double tripCost = (distanceInMiles / fuelEfficiency) * pricePerGallon;
System.out.println("The trip cost (dollars): " + tripCost);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `distanceInMiles`, `fuelEfficiency` and `pricePerGallon` in `double` using `s.nextDouble()`.
After that you should be able to perform `double` operation on these variables.

```
public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter your distance (miles): ");
    double distanceInMiles = s.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("The distance (miles): " + distanceInMiles);

    System.out.print("Please enter vehicle's fuel efficiency (mpg): ");
    double fuelEfficiency = s.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Fuel efficiency (mpg):" + fuelEfficiency);

    System.out.print("Please enter the price per gallon (dollars): ");
    double pricePerGallon = s.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Price per gallon (dollars): " + pricePerGallon);

    double tripCost = (distanceInMiles / fuelEfficiency) * pricePerGallon;

    System.out.println("The trip cost (dollars): " + tripCost);
  }
```

Comment: 1. use `double` and not `Double`. 2. Use only one Scanner. 3. Change the position of the prints and Scanner asks because here they are not in good order

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do calculations with strings. You have to parse doubles out of your string inputs. Just change your equation line to this:

```
double tripCost = (Double.valueOf(distanceInMiles) / Double.valueOf(fuelEfficiency)) * Double.valueOf(pricePerGallon);
```

P.S. Proper input validation would be a good improvement. In case user provide incorrect input. Also, as mentioned in the comments there is no need to use multiple `Scanners`. One will be enough.